# WCF Using X509 Private key for outgoing messages

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security, soapui, x509

So, here is my million dollar question. I want to consume a service hosted by a third party, and therefore for the set up we exchanged X509 certificates. I sent them ours and we got theirs. I added their self signed certificate in the certificate store. Now, I have tried to connect to the services with soapUI, where i need to create a JKS file with my private key to connect, and use the WSSE headers for username, password, nonce and TTL and it works just fine.

But, I want to write a WCF c# client to communicate with the service, and adding my certificate to the client credentials in the config or through code does not work. Can someone please let me know how to use the private key for out going messages using WCF?

I have tried both these things, but not sure where am i going wrong...

```
proxy.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\soapUI\soapUI\Agency1\certificates\myprivatekey.pfx", "Pwd");
proxy.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\soapUI\soapUI\Agency1\certificates\myprivatekey.pfx", "Pwd");
```

i have also added the correct wsu and wsse headers to the soap envelope. When i take the soap envelope from the WCF client to SOAPUI, it works, but not from WCF itself. So i am pretty sure its the difference in how the private keys are being used. So any line of thought will be helpful.

Comment: I have the same question. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

In this article, we will start with transport and message security understanding. We will then see simple code samples of how to implement transport and message security using WsHTTP bindings. We will also see the differences between ‘BasicHttpBinding’ and ‘WsHttpBinding’ with the help of a simple code. WCF security is a huge topic by itself, but I am sure with this article you will get a quick start of how to go about WCF security.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36732/WCF-FAQ-Part-3-10-security-related-FAQ